# SQL Server Reporting Service Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am getting the following error while trying to connect with SQL server Reporting Service. The error is "**The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version**"

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Check your connection information"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this troubleshooting checklist will be useful ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/11/04/you-encounter-report-server-connection-failure-with-below-error-message-below-is-one-of-the-instance-which-i-witnessed-while-connecting-through-ssms-it-fails-while-using-the-server-name-servernameabc.aspx))

1. Try to connect to SQL Server reporting service in SQL Server management studio using `http://localhost/reportserver`  or `http://servername/reportserver`
2. Check if this is successful.
3. If connection to SSRS is successful with `http://localhost/reportserver`  and fails with `<server name>`
4. Modify the rsreportserver.config as `<URL ROOT>http://SERVERNAME/reportserver <URL ROOT>`